# plv8 query example with IN operator

Tags: javascript, postgresql, psql, plv8

I am having trouble executing this query

```
var insurers = [];  
var valid_insurer_query = plv8.execute('select * from table_name where row_id IN $1', [insurers])
```

It is giving syntax error

```
Error: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

It works fine if I use the query

```
var valid_insurer_query = plv8.execute('select * from table_name where row_id = $1', [insurer])  // here insurer is some entry from insurers.
```

I think it is creating trouble because psql query is unable to use javascript array as list.
But I don't know how can I fix this issue ?
Can anyone suggest some solution ? Can anyone share an example on how to use IN query in plv8 ?

Comment: You already seem to know the answer.  Why don't you use the one that works?

Comment: Both of the statements have different purpose. Second one doesn't solve my purpose. I need to get the rows for which row_id is in the list.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow read your 2nd one as `=ANY($1)` rather than =$1

Comment: Thanks. It works with `=ANY($1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use plv8, but IN works with lists and lists can't be stored in parameters.  What you appear to have is an array.  For arrays, you use:

```
=ANY($1)
```